# Can I split a .txt corpus based on first appearance of each item in a list (in python)?

Tags: python, list, text, split

I have a large .txt corpus which I would like to text.split() into its subsections based on the first appearance of each item in a list, as follows:

```
"No. 1.", "No. 2.", "No. 3." etc. up to "No. 4800."
```

These values mark the start of each new document that I want to divide the full corpus into and create a document term matrix for. Within a document, these numbers appear several times but the first appearance always marks the start of the new document.

Splitting on "No. " hasn't worked as there are many other instances of it in the text. I've created a list of all the No. 1-4800 indicators, but cant figure out how to split the text based on that list. Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this sounds like a job for regex https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: It would help if you provide an exact description/sample of the input file.

Comment: \n\n No. 1. text text text. \n\nNo. 2. text text text. \n\nNo. 3. text text text. etc up to No. 4800.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar issue, I was able to solve it using this code below:

```
myfile2 = re.split("\n\nNo.\s[1-5000].\n", myfile)
```

The re.split() was able to detect the digits while my original attempt: myfile.split("\n\nNo.\s[1-5000].\n") was not able to.